# background div color and the color of content div, making them different

Tags: html, css

you are probably confused the way I put,, let me display this. 
when you enter http://www.golfledger.com/ or http://snapzu.com/ the background color is grey but the section that has contents is white. How do I make my html look that way? is it setting the background just grey and the contents div white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o18s63yz/)

CSS

```
body{
background-color:#CCC;
 }
 #main{
 width:70%;
 height:600px;
 top:20px;
 margin-left:15%;
 background-color:#FFF;
 }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
```